# Shortcut for making arrow function snippet in sublime

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I use `Typescript` for my `ionic` projects. I would like to know if there is shortcut for inserting `arrow function` in sublime. ie,

```
(x) => {}
```

somethings like typing `[ar]+tab` inserts this.

Comment: Why don't you create one?

Comment: As I know, no. As you can find [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/general-discussion) specifications and improvements in last version, there is nothing replated to ES6 syntaxt. You  should create a shortcut yourself.

Comment: @DaveGomez @manga i know how to create one by shortcut like ``ctrl+a`` but how do I create with ``tab`` ?

Comment: Google? http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-code-snippets/

Comment: nevermind.. found the way to create..

Comment: Thanks @DaveGomez that explains it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the tabTrigger to anything you want to

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
 (${1:param}) => \{
    ${2:content}
 }
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>=></tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

you can save it to `packages/user/arrow-func.sublime-snippet` in your sublime folder

Comment: This works, but it's actually invalid XML. Should be ` <tabTrigger>=&gt;</tabTrigger>`.